# Outlook VSTO to Office Add-in migration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, outlook, vsto, office-addins

We have created an Outlook VSTO add-in for Windows. Now the plan is to make the software available for other platforms too (Web and ios).

I found [Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins#how-are-office-add-ins-different-from-com-and-vsto-add-ins) which will be an efficient way because the same code is supposed to run on every platform.

**The challenge we have is to reflect all the features in our existing VSTO add-in to the new Office add-in.**

---

The main feature and challenge we are focusing on:

*Generating text inside the editable mail window (before signature) on OnNewMessageCompose(includes reply, reply all, and forward)*

According to the [Event-based activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch#how-to-preview-the-event-based-activation-feature) tutorial, the feature shouldn't be used in production add-ins.

> This feature is only supported for preview in Outlook on the web with a Microsoft 365 subscription. See How to preview the event-based activation feature in this article for more details.
> Because preview features are subject to change without notice, they shouldn't be used in production add-ins.

Currently, I cannot see any working solution for this particular requirement. **Can anybody guide me that how I can migrate from VSTO to Office add-in with taking care of this particular requirement?**

Comment: As the document says, still its in preview. If you look for production one, then you need to wait till it becomes GA (generally available). Till the time you can test the feature in your test bed, share the feedback to Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, @dev. But do we have any other approach? Because I don't know when it will become GA.

Comment: Thats correct. You may need to wait for this feature. Unfortunately i don't remember any alternate way with office web add-ins.